# Why Is It That The View In MVC Is Not Being Displayed?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I had debug and it actually enter the View(survey) but The View is not returning the page. Any help will be appreciated!

//#edit is a submit button, and below is the script.

```
 $('#edit').click(function () {

    var sid = $('input[type=radio]:checked').val();
    var srid = sid.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
    var id = parseInt(srid);
    //alert(id);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("Edit","MainPage")',
        data: { "id": id },
        success: function (result) {

        }

    });


});
```

//Controller

```
[HttpPost]
     public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
         survey survey = db.surveys.Single(s => s.SurveyId == id);
         if (survey == null)
         {
             return HttpNotFound();
         }
        return View(survey);
    }
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, your `HttpNotFound()` will never be accessed, because `Single` will throw an exception when there are no record.  Perhaps you wanted `SingleOrDefault()`?

Comment: if not how should I go about doing it to detect selected radiobutton and button click to submit to controller?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something with the `result` variable in the callback, which will contain the HTML source.

Comment: Hmmm... How should I do that? I do not know what I have to put for my controller to call back because of View(survey)

Comment: It is entering the view but just cannot redirect to the page, I do not know why?